Object created in function triggered by emitter does not run constructor
I'm working on expanding on the tutorial found here
I currently am creating two classes based off of menu
class Menu extends Phaser.GameObjects.Container{
    constructor (x, y, scene, heroes)
    {
        super(scene,x,y);
        this.menuItems = [];
        this.menuItemIndex = -1;
        this.heroes = heroes;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;

    }
    Menu(x, y, scene, heroes) {
        Phaser.GameObjects.Container.call(this, scene, x, y);
        this.menuItems = [];
        this.menuItemIndex = -1;
        this.heroes = heroes;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    addMenuItem(unit){
        var menuItem = new MenuItem(0, this.menuItems.length * 20, unit, this.scene);
        this.menuItems.push(menuItem);
        this.add(menuItem);
    }

    moveSelectionUp(){
        this.menuItems[this.menuItemIndex].deselect();
        this.menuItemIndex--;
        if(this.menuItemIndex < 0)
            this.menuItemIndex = this.menuItems.length - 1;
        this.menuItems[this.menuItemIndex].select();
    }

    moveSelectionDown(){
        this.menuItems[this.menuItemIndex].deselect();
        this.menuItemIndex++;
        if(this.menuItemIndex >= this.menuItems.length)
            this.menuItemIndex = 0;
        this.menuItems[this.menuItemIndex].select();
    }

    select(index){
        if(!index)
            index = 0;
        if(this.menuItemIndex != -1){
            this.menuItems[this.menuItemIndex].deselect();
        }
        this.menuItemIndex = index;
        this.menuItems[this.menuItemIndex].select();
    }

    deselect(){
        this.menuItems[this.menuItemIndex].deselect();
        this.menuItemIndex = 0;
    }

    confirm(){

    }
}

 class AttackMenu extends Menu{
    constructor (x,y,scene)
    {
        super(x,y,scene);
        this.addMenuItem('Sword');
        this.addMenuItem('Staff');
        this.select(0);
    }

    confirm(){
        console.log("further");
    }
}

class ActionsMenu extends Menu{
    constructor (x,y,scene)
    {
        super(x,y,scene);
        this.addMenuItem('Attack');
        this.addMenuItem('Defend');
        this.select(0);
    }
    confirm(){
        this.scene.events.emit('SelectWeapon');
    }
}

My code for actually creating the first class and setting up the listener is here
export default function CreateMenu(view){
    view.graphics = view.add.graphics();
    view.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xffffff);
    view.graphics.fillStyle(0x031f4c, 1);        
    view.graphics.strokeRect(2, 150, 90, 100);
    view.graphics.fillRect(2, 150, 90, 100);
    view.graphics.strokeRect(95, 150, 90, 100);
    view.graphics.fillRect(95, 150, 90, 100);
    view.graphics.strokeRect(188, 150, 130, 100);
    view.graphics.fillRect(188, 150, 130, 100);

    view.menus = view.add.container();
    view.actionsMenu = new ActionsMenu(100, 153, view);            
    view.enemiesMenu = new EnemiesMenu(8, 153, view);  
    

    view.currentMenu = view.actionsMenu;
        
        // add menus to the container
    view.menus.add(view.actionsMenu);
    view.menus.add(view.enemiesMenu);
  

    view.input.keyboard.on('keydown', onKeyInput,view);
    view.events.on("selectWeapon", selectWeapon,view);

}

Here are the 2 listener functions
function onKeyInput(event){
    console.log(event);
    console.log(this);
    console.log(this.currentMenu);
        if(this.currentMenu) {
        if(event.code === "ArrowUp") {
            this.currentMenu.moveSelectionUp();
        } else if(event.code === "ArrowDown") {
            this.currentMenu.moveSelectionDown();
        } else if(event.code === "ArrowRight" || event.code === "Shift") {
        } else if(event.code === "Space" || event.code === "Enter") {
            this.currentMenu.confirm();
        } 
    }
}

function selectWeapon(event){
    this.graphics.fillStyle('green')
    this.graphics.strokeRect(350,150,90,100);
    this.graphics.fillRect(350,150,90,100);
    this.AttackMenu = new AttackMenu(355, 153, this);
    this.menus.add(this.AttackMenu);
    this.currentMenu = AttackMenu;
}


The issue I am running into is that the ActionsMenu controls are working as expected, but when I press enter to bring up the AttackMenu, it gives the error no function exists for moveSelectionUp(). Since AttackMenu inherits from Menu it should already be defined. When I check the outputs, it shows ActionsMenu as a complete object, but for AttackMenu it only shows the definition of the class (the super call plus the specifics of the object)

My question is what am I doing wrong? I am new to Javascript and Phaser and Game Design so I'm not sure if this is an issue with being unable to create a new object off of an emitter, poor game design, or not knowing a way to force the constructor to return the object. Should the object be created first and then only showed when the emitter emits the signal?

Please share error messages as text, not as images. It looks like you did not correctly bind "this" to refer to the object that that has these methods, so instead it's referring to the context in which the event was fired. StackOverflow has existing Q&A about solving that problem — does that cover what you need?

Is this question solved.or do you need some more help?

The issue is probably this line:
function selectWeapon(event){
    ...
    // => the "this." is missing
    this.currentMenu = AttackMenu; 
}

it should be
function selectWeapon(event){
    ...
    this.currentMenu = this.AttackMenu; 
}

Since I assume, you want to assign the created AttackMenu intance (= this.AttackMenu) and not the Class.
